# Only display element during specific article

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am creating a single page scrolling site that has a few articles with fixed backgrounds and fixed items to be displayed only during that article. I am currently the fixed element based on pixels scrolled (as below)

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
$('#portslider').toggle($(this).scrollTop() < 4295);
});
```

I thought that this solved my problem of only wanting to show the fixed elements only each in their own article. However once I started working on making the site responsive I realized this is was not going to work. A few of the other articles need to change length based on screen width, which changes the pixel length where all of the items would need to hide.

So the site looks great at screen size over 2300px and then as you shrink down and the articles change size the fixed elements (weddings, life, adventure, etc...) are no longer hiding at the right scroll length.

A few ideas that I thought of but have not been able to figure out how to proceed with:

1. Can I with Jquery have the item display only within a certain article using the id instead of pixels scrolled?
2. Or can is there a way to use media queries on the above code to change the pixel length at different screen sizes?

You can view the site here: http://s416809079.onlinehome.us/ 
(still under construction and there is a lot not completed yet, best view in firefox so far)

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you set the pixel height of each element to the pixel position of the top of the article? You can get that via jQuery...

Comment: @tkone I don't totally understand. Would that toggle display based on the distance from the top of the page to the article? I am pretty new to Jquery. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a DOM like:

```
<body>
     <article id="article1">[article in here]</article>
     <article id="article2">[article in here]</article>
</body>
```

(these could be `<div>` tags as well...), you can do something like this to set the `toggle` at the correct height no matter what. (You might have to tweak the pixels based on box model, padding, margins, etc):

```
 $(document).scroll(function(){
     $('#portslider').toggle($(this).scrollTop() < $('#article2').css('top'));
 });
```

This way, no matter what the pixel position of the "top" of the article is, `#portslider` will appear correctly.  (You might need to listen to window.resize events too...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One thing that I should have pointed out is that the #portslider (and the other elements like it) are not actually in the article. They are actually below the article, placed on top with negative margin. I couldn't figure out how to place them in the article in wordpress since you can't use jquery in a post. Hope this makes sense. Would this change how I would have to use the above code? Thanks!